# C#, regular expressions : how to parse comma-separated values, where some values might be quoted strings themselves containing commas

Tags: c#, regex, csv

In C#, using the `Regex` class, how does one parse comma-separated values, where some values might be quoted strings themselves containing commas?

```
using System ;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions ;

class  Example
    {
    public static void Main ( )
        {
        string  myString  =  "cat,dog,\"0 = OFF, 1 = ON\",lion,tiger,'R = red, G = green, B = blue',bear" ;
        Console.WriteLine ( "\nmyString is ...\n\t" + myString + "\n" ) ;
        Regex   regex  =  new Regex  (  "(?<=,(\"|\')).*?(?=(\"|\'),)|(^.*?(?=,))|((?<=,).*?(?=,))|((?<=,).*?$)"  )  ;
        Match   match  =  regex.Match ( myString ) ;
        int j = 0 ;
        while ( match.Success )
            {
            Console.WriteLine ( j++ + " \t" + match ) ;
            match  =  match.NextMatch() ;
            }
        }
    }
```

Output (in part) appears as follows:

```
0       cat
1       dog
2       "0 = OFF
3        1 = ON"
4       lion
5       tiger
6       'R = red
7        G = green
8        B = blue'
9       bear
```

However, *desired* output is:

```
0       cat
1       dog
2       0 = OFF, 1 = ON
3       lion
4       tiger
5       R = red, G = green, B = blue
6       bear
```

Comment: Rather than starting with the solution -- regular expressions -- and trying to apply the problem to it, consider going the other way. Start with the problem and pick the tool that clearly solves it well. I personally would solve this problem by writing a lexer for your language. That code is likely to be more clear, understandable, debuggable and extensible than the modem line noise that is a regular expression.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try with this Regex:

```
"[^"\r\n]*"|'[^'\r\n]*'|[^,\r\n]*
```

---

```
    Regex regexObj = new Regex(@"""[^""\r\n]*""|'[^'\r\n]*'|[^,\r\n]*");
    Match matchResults = regexObj.Match(input);
    while (matchResults.Success) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine(matchResults.Value);
        matchResults = matchResults.NextMatch();
    }
```

Ouputs:

- cat
- dog
- "0 = OFF, 1 = ON"
- lion
- tiger
- 'R = red, G = green, B = blue'
- bear

**Note:** This regex solution will work for your case, however I recommend you to use a specialized library like [FileHelpers](http://www.filehelpers.com/).

Comment: For me, your latest edited answer yields the following output:  
0       cat
1
2       dog
3
4       "0 = OFF, 1 = ON"
5
6       lion
7
8       tiger
9
10      'R = red, G = green, B = blue'
11
12      bear
13

Comment: @CMS:  I was able to get your idea to work for me, but I had to make a small modification (replacing * by + at the end).  My Regex is ... new Regex ( @"""[^""\r\n]*""|'[^'\r\n]*'|[^,\r\n]+" )

Comment: Almost forgot:  Thank you, CMS, and others for your valuable input.

Comment: Whoops ... spoke too soon ... my "solution" does not work when some fields are "empty" ... see, for example, the two consecutive commas following cat:  
"cat,,dog,\"0 = OFF, 1 = ON\",lion,tiger,'R = red, G = green, B = blue',bear"

Comment: CSV isn't regular - regexes will *never* be able to parse all valid CVS files. like ever. This is madness except as a dirty hack...

Comment: Here is what I have finally settled on ...  
  string  regexString  =  ""
   + "((?<=\")[^\"]*(?=\"))"  // " ... to ... "
   + "|((?<=\')[^\']*(?=\'))" // ' ... to ... '
   + "|(^[^,]*(?=,))"   // ^ ... to ... ,
   + "|((?<=,)[^,]*$)"   // , ... to ... $
   + "|(?<=,).{0}(?=,)" // ,,
   + "|(?<=,)([^\"\'].*?)(?=,)" // , ... ( excluding " ' ) to ... ,
   ;

  Regex   regex  =  new Regex ( regexString ) ;

Comment: @JaysonFix would you mind posting that solution in your question? I've got exactly the same problem and your solution is a little difficult to read in a comment like that.

Answer (score 22):

Why not heed the advice from the experts and [Don't roll your own CSV parser](http://secretgeek.net/csv_trouble.asp).

Your first thought is, "I need to handle commas inside of quotes."

Your next thought will be, "Oh, crap, I need to handle quotes inside of quotes. Escaped quotes. Double quotes. Single quotes..."

It's a road to madness. Don't write your own. Find a library with an extensive unit test coverage that hits all the hard parts and has gone through hell for you. For .NET, use the free and open source [FileHelpers library](http://www.filehelpers.com/).

Comment: This was my very first thought, too.

Comment: Another reason: the CSV spec is actually surprisingly complex, considering all the different ways of quoting and delimiting values. Not to mention the fact that there *isn't* actually a spec for CSV … (There's RfC4180, but that explicitly states that it is only an "attempt" at a common spec, and that actual implementations vary.) So, chances are, if you roll your own, you'll do it wrong.

Comment: I found CsvHelper to work great and it's in NuGet (http://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/). It's licensed MS-PL which is less scary than the LGPL licensed FileHelpers library if you have a commercial product.

Comment: After I discovered that this wasn't an ad, but a serious library, I found that taking the snippets that I needed, and use them got me the best solution: The smallest library of what I needed, and reliable code when using FileHelpers.

Answer (score 8):

it's not a regex, but I've used Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser to accomplish this for csv files. yes, it might feel a little strange adding a reference to Microsoft.VisualBasic in a C# app, maybe even a little dirty, but hey it works.

Comment: +1 Excellent solution in my case. It is installed with the framework so no extra assemblies to add to the installer and no additional bunch of source files for a simple task.

Answer (score 8):

Ah, RegEx. Now you have two problems. ;)

I'd use a tokenizer/parser, since it is quite straightforward, and more importantly, much easier to read for later maintenance.

This works, for example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string myString = "cat,dog,\"0 = OFF, 1 = ON\",lion,tiger,'R = red, G = green,     B = blue',bear"; 
        Console.WriteLine("\nmyString is ...\n\t" + myString + "\n");
        CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(myString);

        Int32 lineNumber = 0;
        foreach (string s in parser)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(lineNumber + ": " + s);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

internal enum TokenType
{
    Comma,
    Quote,
    Value
}

internal class Token
{
    public Token(TokenType type, string value)
    {
        Value = value;
        Type = type;
    }

    public String Value { get; private set; }
    public TokenType Type { get; private set; }
}

internal class StreamTokenizer : IEnumerable<Token>
{
    private TextReader _reader;

    public StreamTokenizer(TextReader reader)
    {
        _reader = reader;    
    }

    public IEnumerator<Token> GetEnumerator()
    {
        String line;
        StringBuilder value = new StringBuilder();

        while ((line = _reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            foreach (Char c in line)
            {
                switch (c)
                {
                    case '\'':
                    case '"':
                        if (value.Length > 0)
                        {
                            yield return new Token(TokenType.Value, value.ToString());
                            value.Length = 0;
                        }
                        yield return new Token(TokenType.Quote, c.ToString());
                        break;
                    case ',':
                       if (value.Length > 0)
                        {
                            yield return new Token(TokenType.Value, value.ToString());
                            value.Length = 0;
                        }
                        yield return new Token(TokenType.Comma, c.ToString());
                        break;
                    default:
                        value.Append(c);
                        break;
                }
            }

            // Thanks, dpan
            if (value.Length > 0) 
            {
                yield return new Token(TokenType.Value, value.ToString()); 
            }
        }
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}

internal class CsvParser : IEnumerable<String>
{
    private StreamTokenizer _tokenizer;

    public CsvParser(Stream data)
    {
        _tokenizer = new StreamTokenizer(new StreamReader(data));
    }

    public CsvParser(String data)
    {
        _tokenizer = new StreamTokenizer(new StringReader(data));
    }

    public IEnumerator<string> GetEnumerator()
    {
        Boolean inQuote = false;
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (Token token in _tokenizer)
        {
            switch (token.Type)
            {
                case TokenType.Comma:
                    if (inQuote)
                    {
                        result.Append(token.Value);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        yield return result.ToString();
                        result.Length = 0;
                    }
                    break;
                case TokenType.Quote:
                    // Toggle quote state
                    inQuote = !inQuote;
                    break;
                case TokenType.Value:
                    result.Append(token.Value);
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("Unknown token type: " +    token.Type);
            }
        }

        if (result.Length > 0)
        {
            yield return result.ToString();
        }
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Comment: There's a bug in this implementation. In IEnumerator<Token> GetEnumerator() method, you need to add    "if (value.Length > 0) { yield return new Token(TokenType.Value, value.ToString()); }" within the while loop, at the end. Otherwise you are missing the final token

Comment: Thanks @dpan, fixed

Answer (score 7):

Just adding the solution I worked on this morning.

```
var regex = new Regex("(?<=^|,)(\"(?:[^\"]|\"\")*\"|[^,]*)");

foreach (Match m in regex.Matches("<-- input line -->"))
{
    var s = m.Value; 
}
```

As you can see, you need to call regex.Matches() **per line**.  It will then return a MatchCollection with the same number of items you have as columns.  The Value property of each match is, obviously, the parsed value.

This is still a work in progress, but it happily parses CSV strings like:

```
2,3.03,"Hello, my name is ""Joshua""",A,B,C,,,D
```

Comment: @Joshua, This is the best regexfor splitting a string I've found.  And I've tried quite a few.  The magic appears to be at the `(?<=^|,)` part.  Most similar solutions have `:^` rather than `<=^`.  The other solutions will be incorrect for ",,1" reducing it down to a match of 2, yours correctly identifies 3.  Thank you.

Comment: This is a fantastic solution.

Answer (score 4):

CSV is not [regular](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language). Unless your regex language has sufficient power to handle the stateful nature of csv parsing (unlikely, the MS one does not) then any pure regex solution is a list of bugs waiting to happen as you hit a new input source that isn't *quite* handled by the last regex.

CSV reading is not that complex to write as a state machine since the grammar is simple but even so you must consider: quoted quotes, commas within quotes, new lines within quotes, empty fields.

As such you should probably just use someone else's CSV parser. I recommend [CSVReader](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/CsvReader.aspx) for .Net

Answer (score 2):

Function:

```
    private List<string> ParseDelimitedString (string arguments, char delim = ',')
    {
        bool inQuotes = false;
        bool inNonQuotes = false; //used to trim leading WhiteSpace

        List<string> strings = new List<string>();

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (char c in arguments)
        {
            if (c == '\'' || c == '"')
            {
                if (!inQuotes)
                    inQuotes = true;
                else
                    inQuotes = false;
            }else if (c == delim)
            {
                if (!inQuotes)
                {
                    strings.Add(sb.Replace("'", string.Empty).Replace("\"", string.Empty).ToString());
                    sb.Remove(0, sb.Length);
                    inNonQuotes = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    sb.Append(c);
                }
            }
            else if ( !char.IsWhiteSpace(c) && !inQuotes && !inNonQuotes)  
            {
                if (!inNonQuotes) inNonQuotes = true;
                sb.Append(c);
            }
        }
        strings.Add(sb.Replace("'", string.Empty).Replace("\"", string.Empty).ToString());


        return strings;
    }
```

Usage

```
    string myString = "cat,dog,\"0 = OFF, 1 = ON\",lion,tiger,'R = red, G = green, B = blue',bear,         text";
    List<string> strings = ParseDelimitedString(myString);

    foreach( string s in strings )
            Console.WriteLine( s );
```

Output:

```
cat
dog
0 = OFF, 1 = ON
lion
tiger
R = red, G = green, B = blue
bear
text
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a few bugs in that version, for example, a non-quoted string that has a single quote in the value.

And I agree use the FileHelper library when you can, however that library requires you know what your data will look like... I need a generic parser.

So I've updated the code to the following and thought I'd share...

```
    static public List<string> ParseDelimitedString(string value, char delimiter)
    {
        bool inQuotes = false;
        bool inNonQuotes = false;
        bool secondQuote = false;
        char curQuote = '\0';

        List<string> results = new List<string>();

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (char c in value)
        {
            if (inNonQuotes)
            {
                // then quotes are just characters
                if (c == delimiter)
                {
                    results.Add(sb.ToString());
                    sb.Remove(0, sb.Length);
                    inNonQuotes = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    sb.Append(c);
                }
            }
            else if (inQuotes)
            {
                // then quotes need to be double escaped
                if ((c == '\'' && c == curQuote) || (c == '"' && c == curQuote))
                {
                    if (secondQuote)
                    {
                        secondQuote = false;
                        sb.Append(c);
                    }
                    else
                        secondQuote = true;
                }
                else if (secondQuote && c == delimiter)
                {
                    results.Add(sb.ToString());
                    sb.Remove(0, sb.Length);
                    inQuotes = false;
                }
                else if (!secondQuote)
                {
                    sb.Append(c);
                }
                else
                {
                    // bad,as,"user entered something like"this,poorly escaped,value
                    // just ignore until second delimiter found
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // not yet parsing a field
                if (c == '\'' || c == '"')
                {
                    curQuote = c;
                    inQuotes = true;
                    inNonQuotes = false;
                    secondQuote = false;
                }
                else if (c == delimiter)
                {
                    // blank field
                    inQuotes = false;
                    inNonQuotes = false;
                    results.Add(string.Empty);
                }
                else
                {
                    inQuotes = false;
                    inNonQuotes = true;
                    sb.Append(c);
                }
            }
        }

        if (inQuotes || inNonQuotes)
            results.Add(sb.ToString());

        return results;
    }
```

Comment: Found bugs in *which* version?  Answers don't appear in a fixed order, so if you want to reference another answer, it's best to link to it directly.  The `share` button below the answer provides the appropriate URL.

Answer (score 0):

since this question: [Regex to to parse csv with nested quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7947294/regex-to-to-parse-csv-with-nested-quotes)

reports here and is much more generic, and since a RegEx is not really the proper way to solve this problem (i.e. I have had many issues with catastrophic backtracking (http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html)

here is a simple parser implementation in Python as well

```
def csv_to_array(string):
    stack = []
    match = []
    matches = []

    for c in string:
        # do we have a quote or double quote?
        if c == "\"":
            # is it a closing match?
            if len(stack) > 0 and stack[-1] == c:
                stack.pop()
            else:
                stack.append(c)
        elif (c == "," and len(stack) == 0) or (c == "\n"):
            matches.append("".join(match))
            match = []
        else:
            match.append(c)

    return matches
```