# Spit string with ',' delimiter and data encoded with ' '

Tags: c#, .net, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C#, regular expressions : how to parse comma-separated values, where some values might be quoted strings themselves containing commas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1189416/c-regular-expressions-how-to-parse-comma-separated-values-where-some-values)

I am actually processing a text file that the data is like that

```
    //Sample Structure = 'Name','Address','TelNumber'
    Sting OriginalData= "'Mr Worgon','27,4 Streeat A,US', '60231212'";
```

I am try with

```
    String[] SampleData;
    String ABC1,ABC2,ABC3;

    SampleData = OriginalData.Split(',');
    ABC1 = SampleData[0];
    ABC2 = SampleData[1];
    ABC3 = SampleData[2];
```

but its seem it not suitable because of the Address Data that mostly will have a ','.

Any suggestion for this kind of String controlling?

Comment: Don't use `String.Split` to parse a csv file but use one of the available csv-parsers. The [`TextFieldParser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx) is already available in the framework(VisualBasic.dll  but can be used also with C#).

Comment: Try @"""[^""\r\n]*""|'[^'\r\n]*'|[^,\r\n]*". It will provide the output you are expecting. It is from the link, David specified.

Comment: DavidBrunow link not useful?

Answer (score -1):

Can do like:

```
string OriginalData= "'Mr Worgon','27,4 Streeat A,US', '60231212'";
var split = OriginalData.Split('\'');
```

and after

```
ABC1 = SampleData[1];
ABC2 = SampleData[3];
ABC3 = SampleData[5];
```

in other words, every second splitted array element, in this concrete case.

Comment: Not my downvote, but consider `Mr O'Malley`.