# Reading CSV file and storing values into an dictionary

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm, csv, dictionary

I am trying to read a `test.csv` file. Like this;

```
"test.try1.get1","START"

"test.try1.get2","Get 111"
"test.try1.get3","Get 222, 333"
"test.try1.get4","Get {test}, [{test2}, {test3]"
"test.try1.get5","Get \"{test}\", [{test2}, {test3]"


"test.try2.get1","Bla bla bla... bla bla bla...
Bla bla bla bla bla bla bla...
Bla bla bla bla bla bla bla... (:

BLA?"

"test.try2.get2","Bla bla bla... bla bla bla...

 • 1 - Bla bla bla bla bla bla bla...
 • 2 - Bla bla bla bla bla bla bla...

Bla bla bla \" bla bla bla bla... (: \"

BLA?"

"test.try3.get1","BONUSSS!!!"
"test.try3.get2","BONUSSS!!! \" "

"test.try4.get1","END"
```

I am able to read the `test.csv` file using `StreamReader` and able to separate each line by using the `Split()` function. I want to store each column into a separate dictionary and then display it. Like ;

```
Console.WriteLine(GetText(test.try1.get1)); //OUTPUT: START (WITHOUT ("))
```

I think, this code is bad.

-How can I improve the performance ? 
-How do I shorten this code ?
-Is "The logic of code" good ?
-Can someone help me ? (:

MY NOT Working code ;

```
public static Dictionary<string, string> texts = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    public static void LoadCSV() {
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"test.csv")) {

            string total = string.Empty;
            bool multipleLine = false;

            while (!reader.EndOfStream) {
                string line = reader.ReadLine().ToString();

                if (!multipleLine && line.StartsWith("\"") && !line.EndsWith("\"") && line != string.Empty) {
                    multipleLine = true;
                }

                if(multipleLine && line == string.Empty) {
                    total += "\n\n";
                    continue;
                }

                if (!multipleLine && line == string.Empty) {
                    continue;
                }

                if (multipleLine && !line.StartsWith("\"") && !line.EndsWith("\"") && line != string.Empty) {
                    total += line;
                    continue;
                }
                else if (multipleLine && !line.StartsWith("\"") && line.EndsWith("\"") && line != string.Empty) {
                    total += line;
                    multipleLine = false;
                }

                if (!multipleLine && line.StartsWith("\"") && line.EndsWith("\"") && line != string.Empty) {
                    total = line;
                }

                string[] splitted = total.Split(',');

                if (!texts.ContainsKey(splitted[0])) {
                    //Index out of range
                    texts.Add(splitted[0].Replace("\"", string.Empty), splitted[1]);
                    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("ADDED : {0} , {1}", splitted[0], splitted[1]));
                }

                total = string.Empty;
                multipleLine = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'd recommend you look into using a CSV parsing library.

Answer (score 0):

If you can guarantee that the size of the file will be reasonable, I'd just read the entire file into memory and run a regex on it.  Then loop through the matches and add them to the dictionary.

The regex given in this SO answer should work for you:

[C#, regular expressions : how to parse comma-separated values, where some values might be quoted strings themselves containing commas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1189416/c-regular-expressions-how-to-parse-comma-separated-values-where-some-values)

Comment: Can you generate a Regex for this ?