# How to allow spaces in the beginning of each row using regex?

Tags: regex, validation, expression

I currently have a validation expression that almost works the way I want it to, only I am having trouble allowing spaces at the beginning of some rows. I'd like to support unlimited spaces at the beginning of rows.

Here is an example and the expression that I am having trouble with:
[^(?=.*?[ \t]*([., \t]))(?:[1-9][0-9]*(?:[ \t]*\1[ \t]*[1-9][0-9]*)+[ \t]*\r?\n?)+$](http://www.regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%28%3F%3D.*%3F%5B%20%5Ct%5D*%28%5B.%2C%20%5Ct%5D%29%29%28%3F%3A%5B1-9%5D%5B0-9%5D*%28%3F%3A%5B%20%5Ct%5D*%5C1%5B%20%5Ct%5D*%5B1-9%5D%5B0-9%5D*%29%2B%5B%20%5Ct%5D*%5Cr%3F%5Cn%3F%29%2B%24&i=10%2011%2012%2013%2014%2030%0D%0A%209%2041%2042%2044%2046%2048%0D%0A10%2011%2012%2013%2014%2030)

Here is the example string I'd like to match:

```
10 11 12 13 14 30
 9 41 42 44 46 48
10 11 12 13 14 30
```

My first question which explains what I want to do specifically is found: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45533583/regex-for-comma-delimited-list-with-line-breaks)

Comment: Could you add to your question an example string you would like to match?

Comment: Will your input only be a string with number and spaces? Your regex seems to be too complex for that.

Comment: No, I will accept multiple delimiter types: commas, spaces, tabs.

Comment: Your regex doesn't make sense. Maybe if you explain in detail what you are trying to do. And especially why the `\1` backreference was used...

Comment: Couldn't `[ \t]*\d+` do what you want?

Comment: So I take it you are trying to validate the entire string all at once using a single delimiter ? Using a lookahead to find the delimiter will always return the same result because it is atomic and won't backtrack.

Comment: @sln Yes, and I'd like to allow spaces at the beginning of rows. I'd like to keep the rest of my expression as is if possible.

Comment: I fear it won't work as is when using a single delimiter.

Comment: @sln \s doesn't work, that's for sure. What do you think is causing the problem?

Comment: I know what the problem is. The solution depends on having more than 1 item on each line. Is that going to be the case?

Comment: @sln can it be fixed if I use only 0-9? There will always be more than one number in each row if that's what you were asking.

Comment: @sln Yes there will always be more than one item on each line.

Comment: Posted a solution for ya.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an advanced topic, this will be a little difficult to understand, but here goes.

`^\s*[1-9][0-9]*\s*(?=([., \t]))(?:\s*(?:\1|\r?\n)\s*[1-9][0-9]*)+\s*$`

You have a unique problem since you are trying to validate all the rows
as a single string.
The problem comes when the delimiter is *not* available at the end of
a row.

To get around that, use an alternation with the backreference (delimiter)
*or* a line break.

As for whitespace at the beginning of string, just intersperse with `\s`.

See here  https://regex101.com/r/nir0uI/1 and here https://regex101.com/r/nir0uI/2

Formatted

```
 ^ 
 \s* 
 [1-9] [0-9]* 
 \s* 
 (?=                                # Lookahead for delimiter.
      ( [., \t] )                   # (1)
 )
 (?:
      \s* 
      (?: \1 | \r? \n )
      \s*       
      [1-9] [0-9]* 
 )+
 \s*  
 $
```

Comment: Wow a true genius thanks so much!!! Will I run into any problems using tabs as delimiters with this solution?

Comment: Also, would it be hard to accept the delimiter at the end of each line? I see that spaces can be added to the end of each line so I pressure that tabs would also work. But how about a single comma (or space-comma) and dot (or space-dot) at the end of each line? depending on which delimiter is used. I know this could be complicating things much more. Tell me if it's too much.

Comment: @justinpees - The regex101 links show the delimiter (group 1) in green highlight. The way it is now, there are 3 conditions around the line break (\r?\n). `No delimiter` or `Delimiter-line break` or `Line break-delimiter`. See https://regex101.com/r/Vll1fT/1. If you want to change one of those conditions, let me know.

Comment: thanks again so much, I think I had another question. I'll send out a comment soon when I remember what it was.

Comment: do you know if it's possible to make a ValidationExpression like this for when I ask users to upload a .txt file? I'd like to validate the content inside the uploaded .txt file. I will make a new question for this. I'd like to know if it's possible first.

Answer (score 1):

```
\s
```

might help at the beginning of your expression.

Comment: I tried that, it doesn't seem to work. You can test it yourself. Is it because I have space set as a delimiter?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to validate?

Answer (score 1):

Add *zero or more whitespace* to the front of your regex:

```
^\s*<your regex here>
```