# Kotlin String.split, ignore when delimiter is inside a quote

Tags: string, split, kotlin

I have a string:

```
Hi there, "Bananas are, by nature, evil.", Hey there.
```

I want to split the string with commas as the delimiter. How do I get the .split method to ignore the comma inside the quotes, so that it returns 3 strings and not 5.

Answer (score 9):

You can use `regex` in split method

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18893443/4035036) the following regex only matches `,` outside of the `"` mark

> ,(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)

so try this code:

```
str.split(",(?=(?:[^\\\"]*\\\"[^\\\"]*\\\")*[^\\\"]*\$)".toRegex())
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use split overload that accepts regular expressions for that:

```
val text = """Hi there, "Bananas are, by nature, evil.", Hey there."""
val matchCommaNotInQuotes = Regex("""\,(?=([^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)""")
println(text.split(matchCommaNotInQuotes))
```

Would print:

```
[Hi there,  "Bananas are, by nature, evil.",  Hey there.]
```

Consider reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6464500/155213) on how the regular expression works in this case.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use a regular expression capable of handling quoted values. See [Java: splitting a comma-separated string but ignoring commas in quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757065/java-splitting-a-comma-separated-string-but-ignoring-commas-in-quotes) and [C#, regular expressions : how to parse comma-separated values, where some values might be quoted strings themselves containing commas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1189416/c-regular-expressions-how-to-parse-comma-separated-values-where-some-values)

The following code shows a very simple version of such a regular expression.

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {

    "Hi there, \"Bananas are, by nature, evil.\", Hey there."
            .split(",(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)".toRegex())
            .forEach { println("> $it") }

}
```

outputs

```
> Hi there
>  "Bananas are, by nature, evil."
>  Hey there.
```

Be aware of the regex backtracking problem: https://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html. You might be better off writing a parser.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want regular expressions:

```
val s = "Hi there, \"Bananas are, by nature, evil.\", Hey there."
val hold = s.substringAfter("\"").substringBefore("\"")
val temp = s.split("\"")
val splitted: MutableList<String> = (temp[0] + "\"" + temp[2]).split(",").toMutableList()
splitted[1] = "\"" + hold + "\""
```

`splitted` is the List you want