# Regular Expression not working when comma is right after quote

Tags: c#, regex

I have the regular expression

```
((?<=\")[^\"]*(?=\"(,|$)+)|(?<=,|^)[^,\"]*(?=,|$))
```

and the string I try to parse

```
"Private",N,,"Gas,Meter."
```

this works properly as I will have Private, N, space, "Gas Meter"

but

```
"Private",N,,",Gas,Meter."
```

will give me

```
Private, ",N,," and then ",Gas,Meter."
```

the regular expression works if , is in between but not right after the quote.

Any idea?

Comment: Seems like you're trying to parse a CSV file/string. What programming language are you using? Most languages have a CSV parser in their standard library. Is there a specific reason you're trying to do this with regex?

Comment: It's unclear how you are hoping for this wreck of a regex to work. *Probably* you would be better off simply with `(?:"([^"]*)"|([^",]*))` but we can't guess which regex dialect you are using or what you are hoping to achieve. See also the [Stack Overflow `regex` tag info page](/tags/regex/info) for guidance on how to ask a proper question and how to tag it correctly.

Comment: Could you use a CSV parser instead Jason? I wonder if that would be more robust.

Comment: If I find one that is not using visual basic dll, I will definitely use it.

Comment: What language/environment are you using?

Comment: C# .net , I don't think they have one built in, the one I know is using visual basic dll.  On the other hand, there is some in GitHub, just wondering which one you guys recommend.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C#, regular expressions : how to parse comma-separated values, where some values might be quoted strings themselves containing commas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1189416/c-regular-expressions-how-to-parse-comma-separated-values-where-some-values)

Answer (score 0):

The general issue with the regular expression is that it checks optionally for a comma at the beginning and then greedily goes until it gets a match of ", or ,. I believe it is checking for ", first so it keeps going until it encounters the ",Gas...". I think switching the two conditions though would instead cause issues with commas within quotes. You should probably just replace this regular expression with the on in this answer.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/42535295/2710988